# Increase call stack size React Native with JSC/Hermes/V8

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

We switched from JSC to Hermes for our React Native app on Android.

Since publishing that change, we got a number of `RangeError: Call stack size exceeded` crash reports.

In the long run, we should fix these recursive calls but for now:

- Is there a difference in call stack size between JSC and Hermes?
- If so: Can this call stack size be configured?

  I know that the call stack size of V8 can be adjusted with `--stack_size`. Is there a similar option for Hermes?

Comment: While this [is configurable](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/blob/dee3b5324b55cbdcf6d72589a8649e297c32874d/public/hermes/Public/RuntimeConfig.h#L50-L51) in Hermes, this configuration option is [not exposed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/38eb3f8dcb4a2a1e24d27916e23330537336dfc6/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/hermes/reactexecutor/RuntimeConfig.java#L11) in React Native's Java API. If you want to change the size without recompiling RN, you can [file a feature request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues).

Comment: @Jonas did you ever find a reason why this was occurring? And if so we're you able to solve it?